# Multiple Timeseries Anomaly Detection - identifying which feature is anomalous?

Tags: python, time-series, anomaly-detection

I have a multivariate time series where I have features such as:

- temperature set point
- energy used
- relative humidity, etc.

Currently, I'm creating univariate anomaly detection models in Python using the likes of local outlier factors and autoencoders, and they work pretty well. I was wondering if there's an approach which allows multivariate anomaly detection, and identifies which of the features (individual or multiple) are showing the anomaly?

From what I can see, the likes of VAR and autoencoders for multinomial data will tell you there is an anomaly, but do not provide the context as to which feature is at fault.

Comment: Consider a gaussian mixture model. Each point can be associated with a probability. Points with a probability below a certain value can be considered an outlier.